airspeed velocity continous failing sporadically
I have a github action file for benchmarks using airspeed velocity.
- name: Compare HEAD with master if PR
        if: github.event_name == 'pull_request_target'
        continue-on-error: true # TODO: step failed sporadically while testing
        run: |
          asv continuous ${{ github.event.pull_request.base.sha }} ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }}  | tee asv-cont-output.log  
          if grep -q failed asv-cont-output.log; then 
            echo "Some benchmarks have errors!"
            exit 1
          fi

This step, most of the times fails by giving the following output:
asv continuous 6fffa6963957d1cedf233cf0f613413b89b60281 7ba43175f36b9ae667ce20c62943e5c57ea3fd7c  | tee asv-cont-output.log  
· Unknown commit 7ba43175f36b9ae667ce20c62943e5c57ea3fd7c

Here is the link for the failed step: https://github.com/tardis-sn/tardis/actions/runs/9419506398/job/25949423881
I am not able to understand why it's happening.
